# Вечная проблема кодировки и строковых переменных

Tags: php, строки, utf-8

Разбиваю строку на предложения с рег. выражением `[.?!]+`.
Потом строку привожу к виду:

Первая буква 1-го предложения с большой буквы `{конкатенация}` остальные буквы с маленькой `{конкатенация}` Первая буква `N`-го предложения с большой буквы `{конкатенация}` и т.д.

Код вкратце так:

```
mb_strtoupper( mb_substr(trim($sentence), 0, 1, 'utf8') 
. 
mb_strtolower( mb_substr(trim($sentence), 1, mb_strlen(trim($sentence), 'UTF8'), 'utf8') );
```

На выходе:
`Д�� �����`

То есть, проблема где-то в `mb_strtolower`. Уже кучу всего прочитал на форумах. Кто-то пишет про какие-то локали (что это?), кто-то пишет, что нужно прописать `mbstring` где-то (нужно ли и где прописать? у меня OpenServer, если что).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать `mb_convert_case` вместо `mb_strtolower`. Заработало...

Спасибо, всем откликнувшимся!